# Keras, how to output a dense layer with different dim length of output?

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm

In the following code I am training a small neural network on a set of features (X_train, length of 2) and labels (y_train, length of 7).
Instead of just outputting the prediction, I am also trying to output the dense_representation_layer:

n_inputs, n_outputs = X_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[1]
#2, 7

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(n_inputs,))
dense_layer = Dense(20, activation='relu')(input_layer)
output_layer = Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid')(dense_layer)
dense_representation_layer = Dense(20, activation='sigmoid')(dense_layer) # ERROR HERE
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output_layer, dense_representation_layer])

model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy', 
    optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape','accuracy']
)

# fit model
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, verbose=2, epochs=epochs)

return model, history
```

However, it tells me that the dimension of the dense_representation_layer must be the same of the output layer:

```
ValueError: logitsandlabels must have the same shape, received ((None, 20) vs (None, 7)).
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you